# Fail2ban blocking IP after unban

Tags: linux, iptables, fail2ban

I cant unban an IP from the server. I removed the address from fail2ban and deleted the entry from iptables, but I still can't login.

My Jail list name is `sshd` (checked with `fail2ban-client status`)

I did `fail2ban-client set sshd unbanip <IP>`

Then  `iptables -L -n --line-numbers` had in `Chain f2b-sshd` a line to REJECT my IP.
I used `iptables -D f2b-sshd <line_number>` to delete my address from the iptables.

I still can't connect. The log /var/log/fail2ban.log contains 
`2019-04-12 13:37:40,963 fail2ban.filter         [22791]: INFO    [sshd] Found <IP> - 2019-04-12 13:37:40`
Did I miss something? Why fail2ban says it found my IP after I unbanned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
I had to delete the line `ALL: <IP>` from the file /etc/hosts.deny and insert a line in the file /etc/hosts.allow
And then `fail2ban-client reload`

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the ban using fail2ban, otherwise it will just re-add it. In your case it should be

`fail2ban-client set f2b-sshd unbanip [banned IP address]`

Comment: I only have the jail sshd in fail2ban.
jail f2b-sshd does not exists
`NOK: ('f2b-sshd',)
Sorry but the jail 'f2b-sshd' does not exist
`
 Found the problem, it was the file /etc/hosts.deny